# Почему возникает Memory Limit Exceed?

Tags: java, алгоритм, производительность, арифметика, теория-чисел

В контесте нужно решить следующую задачу:

На вершине лесенки, содержащей n ступенек, сидит кузнечик, который хочет спуститься вниз, к основанию. Кузнечик умеет прыгать на следующую ступеньку, на ступеньку через одну или через две. Например, если кузнечик сидит на 6-ой ступеньке, то он может прыгнуть на 3-ую, 4-ую или 5-ую ступеньку. Кузнечик всегда прыгает только вниз.

Ваша задача - посчитать количество всевозможных маршрутов кузнечика для спуска с последней ступеньки до основания.

Так как количество маршрутов может быть очень большим, Вам необходимо вывести ответ как остаток от деления результата на (10^9 + 7).

Решил с помощью массива значений:

```
public static BigInteger fooBI2(int n) {
    BigInteger[] vars = new BigInteger[3];
    vars[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(1L);
    vars[1] = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);
    vars[2] = BigInteger.valueOf(4L);
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
        vars[i%3] = vars[0].add(vars[1]).add(vars[2]);
    }
    return vars[(n-1)%3].mod(BigInteger.valueOf((long) (Math.pow(10, 9) + 7)));
}
```

Но почему-то на одном из тестов проваливается в MLE. Который час не могу понять, почему. Нужна подсказка или помощь.

Comment: Кажется мне, что проблема в том, что вы считаете полное количество, а уже потом ищете остаток. И на очень больших значениях памяти для них не хватает. Тут длинная арифметика, вообще-то, ни к чему... Да, *В контексте нужно решить* — точно в *контексте*? :)

Comment: @Harry, что посоветуете предпринять?

Comment: Решать правильно :) Вспомнить, что `(a+b) mod с == (a mod с + b mod c) mod c`

Comment: Какое ограничение на число ступенек?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно, намек был сделан в самой задаче —

> Так как количество маршрутов может быть очень большим, Вам необходимо вывести ответ как остаток от деления результата на (10^9 + 7).

Чтобы вы не пытались работать с очень большими числами, а работали с остатками.

Тут самое время вспомнить, что

```
(a+b) mod с == (a mod с + b mod c) mod c
```

и [переписать ваш код](https://ideone.com/kx8lSO) (помня о том, что сумма трех чисел около миллиарда уже может выпрыгнуть за рамки `int`):

```
public static int fooBI3(int n) {
    int p = 1000000007;
    int[] vars = new int[3];
    vars[0] = 1;
    vars[1] = 2;
    vars[2] = 4;
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
        vars[i%3] = ((vars[0] + vars[1])%p +vars[2])%p;
    }
    return vars[(n-1)%3];
}
```

Comment: Не лишнее ли вычисление остатков в скобках от величин, которые уже взяты по нужному модулю? Кажется, что должно остаться только две операции %p

Comment: @MBo Не лишнее. Грубо, три раза по 999999999 не просто надо брать еще один остаток, но и первые два, сложив, надо брать остаток, потому что иначе вылетим за пределы `int` (я потому и написал это примечание — *помня о том, что сумма трех чисел около миллиарда уже может выпрыгнуть за рамки `int`*). И это не надуманный теоретически момент — попробуйте убрать один `%p` и посмотреть на результат...

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что после сложения двух нужно брать остаток. Я вот про такое: `((vars[0] + vars[1])%p +vars[2])%p;`

Comment: @MBo А, понял! Да, тут я явно перестраховался, согласен. Ведь эти `vars` *уже* взяты по модулю...

Comment: Теперь функция совершенна! :)

Comment: @MBo Только еще название заменить на `tribonacci` :)

Answer (score 0):

Число маршрутов кузнечика равно `g(n) = tribonacci(n + 2)`. Последовательность [tribonacci](https://oeis.org/A000073) устроена точно также как `g`: следующее значение - сумма трёх предыдущих. Надо только подобрать смещение. Трибоначчи отстаёт на два индекса:

> ```
> g:  1  1  2  4  7 13 24
> T:  0  0  1  1  2  4  7 13 24
> ```

Числа трибоначчи можно считать быстрым возведением в степень:

> ```
>                      n
> / T_n   \   / 0 1 0 \  / 0 \
> | T_n+1 | = | 0 0 1 |  | 0 |
> \ T_n+2 /   \ 1 1 1 /  \ 1 /
> ```

Код:

```
public class Grasshopper {

    private static class Triple {
        private final int a;
        private final int b;
        private final int c;

        Triple(int a, int b, int c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
    };

    private static final int MODULO = 1_000_000_007;

    private static int add(int a, int b) {
        return (int)Math.floorMod(a + b, MODULO);
    }

    private static int add(int a, int b, int c) {
        return add(add(a, b), c);
    }

    private static int mul(int a, int b) {
        return (int)Math.floorMod((long)a * b, MODULO);
    }

    private static final Triple UNIT = new Triple(0, 0, 1);

    private static Triple mul(Triple t1, Triple t2) {
        return new Triple(
            add(mul(t1.a, add(t2.c, -t2.b, -t2.a)), mul(add(t1.c, -t1.b), t2.a), mul(t1.b, t2.b)),
            add(mul(t1.a, t2.a                   ), mul(add(t1.c, -t1.b), t2.b), mul(t1.b, t2.c)),
            add(mul(t1.b, t2.a                   ), mul(add(t1.a,  t1.b), t2.b), mul(t1.c, t2.c))
        );
    }

    private static Triple fast_pow(Triple t, long n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return UNIT;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            Triple sqrt = fast_pow(t, n / 2);
            return mul(sqrt, sqrt);
        }
        return mul(t, fast_pow(t, n - 1));
    }

    private static long tribonacci(long n) {
        return fast_pow(new Triple(0, 1, 1), n).a;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            long n = Long.parseLong(arg);
            System.out.println(tribonacci(n + 2));
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac Grasshopper.java
>
> $ time java Grasshopper 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9223372036854775805
> g(0) = 1
> g(1) = 1
> g(2) = 2
> g(3) = 4
> g(4) = 7
> g(5) = 13
> g(6) = 24
> g(7) = 44
> g(8) = 81
> g(9) = 149
> g(10) = 274
> g(9223372036854775805) = 495578506
>
> real  0m0.055s
> user  0m0.052s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

**P.S.** Длина лестницы ограничена типом `long`. Если его заменить на `BigInteger`, программа будет работать для любых лестниц за время пропорциональное количеству цифр в числе.